# Given 1 < a < 10, 1 ≤ n ≤ 100000, show how to compute the value of 1 × a + 2 × a^2 + 3 × a^3 + . . . + n × a^n efficiently, i.e. in O(log n)!

Tags: algorithm, math

I, however, found the `sum(S)` by computing `(S - a*s)`. But how to do it in `O(logn)` I need a good algorithm.

Comment: Given that n has an upper bound you can do it in O(1).

Comment: What does `O(log n)!` mean... did you mean `O(log n!) = O(n log n)` ?

Comment: Thanks Homework Overflow.

Comment: @willywonka_dailyblah: It's the exclamation mark at the end of the assignment. Discuss!

Comment: @MOehm chill bro I wuz just speculating on the possibility of a typo

Comment: `a^n` has a linear number of digits. How on earth could you bound the complexity by `O(Log(n))` ???

Comment: complexity : O(logn)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is homework I guess your professor explained you how to compute Fibonnacci numbers and expect you to use the same trick.

So basically remark that:

```
|1+a+ a²+...+ a^n|   |a 0 1| |1+a+ a²+...+     a^(n-1)|
|  a+2a²+...+na^n| = |a a 1| |  a+2a²+...+(n-1)a^(n-1)|
|1               |   |0 0 1| |1                       |

                     |a 0 1|^n  |1|
                   = |a a 1|    |0|
                     |0 0 1|    |1|
```

You need to do a matrix exponentiation, which is `O(log(n))` if we don't take into account the precision and only use standard machine's operation.

Answer (score 3):

This is the sum

[image]

There's no simple geometric / arithmetic relationship between the terms, so finding an O(log n) method is quite hard; but mathematically it can be done in O(1).

[image]

But this assumes machine-level operations are O(1). And @Yves is right, `a^n` will in fact require an arbitrary-precision number format which will intrinsically be `O(n)` in computational complexity.

Comment: "machine-level operations are O(1)": yep, and this is completely unrealistic.

Comment: I know you know, this is for the OP :)

Answer (score 0):

We can take logarithm of the series and we will find a pattern like

1 X Log(a) + 2 X Log(a^2) + 3 X Log(a^3) + 4 X Log(a^4) +............. + n X Log(a^n) - equation 1

As we know the property of LOG i.e [ Log(a^n) = n x Log(a)] - equation 2

Using above property :
 equation 1 will convert to = 1 X 1 X Log(a) + 2 X 2 X Log(a) + 3 X 3 X Log(a) +....... n X n X Log(a).

Now Take Log(a) out and the equation will become = ( 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 +..... + n^2) X Log(a) :
 which is [ (n(n+1)(2n+1))/6 times Log(a)]. Don't forget to take antilog.

If you find anything incorrect, please tell me in the comment

Comment: What does 1 X Log(a) + 2 X Log(a^2) + 3 X Log(a^3) + 4 X Log(a^4) +............. + n X Log(a^n) have to do with 1 × a + 2 × a^2 + 3 × a^3 + . . . + n × a^n ? Did you get a look at the other answers ?